# Selenium: Iterating over elements of certain type, with varying xpaths?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Working on a Java/Selenium application right now, running into some issues

I have a series of clickable elements on a web page. I would like to generate a list of web elements, to iterate over them and perform specific actions, like opening a new tab with them etc

Each XPATH looks like:

```
//*[@id="msg-1276616953"]/div[8]/div/a[1]
```

where msg = # is the specific identifier of that element

The specific msg-________ changes for each clickable element. ie: the next element might be something different, etc

If there are 20 of those elements on a page, I want to generate a list of all 20, but I'm not sure how to do so in Selenium

I would appreciate any and all help

Here's the source on the element itself:

```
<a data-ng-if="currentSuperState != 'ON_HOLD' 
&amp;&amp; currentSuperState != 'EXPIRED'" target="_self" href="/someLinkId=1276617990" 
class="some-link-begin ng-binding ng-scope" data-btn-loc="my-link">
        Edit-Link
    </a>
```

Comment: Can you also share `HTML` for other 1-2 similar links?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like,

**Find all the Links available on the Page**

```
List<WebElement> elem = driver.findElements(By.TagName("a"));
```

Now u can iterate over the list and do your desired action on the basis of your requirement, for example you can get the attribute(whatever u want to match by using `if (elem.getAttribute("attribute name")).contains("yourDesiredText") {//Then do some Action}` for the particular elem and get your desired result.

You can try something like this for other elements as well.